# Why I can´t run a python program with cmd? (But, with Visual Estudio Code yes)

Tags: python

I can´t run a python program with cmd.

This is my program:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import getpass
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload



# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
User = getpass.getuser()
print ("#---------------------------------------------------------")
print ("                   PROGRAMA PARA SUBIR                    ")
print ("#---------------------------------------------------------")
store = file.Storage('token.json')
creds = store.get()
drive = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
file_metadata = {'name': input(str("Introduce como se quiere llamar tu archivo en la nube (intruduce 
la extensión) EJEMPLO: photo.jpg o Video.mp4 ----->  "))}
media = MediaFileUpload('C:/Users/' + User + '/Desktop/' + input(str("¿Como se llama el archivo q 
quieres subir?----->   ")),
                    mimetype=input(str("Introduce el tipo de archivo que es. EJEMPLO: executable/exe. 
Primero de que tipo es, una / y despues la extensión. Y ten en cuenta q el tipo de archivo tiene q 
estar en ingles---->  ")))
file = drive.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                media_body=media,
                                fields='id').execute()
print ('File ID: %s' % file.get('id'))
```

AND THIS IS THE ERROR (IN CMD):
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Jose Maria\Desktop\Programación\Python\Subir.py", line 27, in 
drive = (build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http())))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'authorize'

Comment: It seems the module `oauth2client` somehow returns you different data.

How exactly you start the code within VS Code and in cmd? Is there a chance that you have two versions of Phyton in your system?

Comment: No, there is only one version of python on my computer

Comment: Help, plis. Can you help me?

Comment: Alas, I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: Could you please run the `where python` command in both VS Code and cmd and post the outputs to us here?